# What is "szone_free_definite_size"?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was profiling (using through Xcode > Instruments) two different versions of C++ project of mine. In one of the versions only, the function `szone_free_definite_size` (from `libsystem_malloc.dylib`) consumes 7% of the CPU time. This function is called in a `T::operator=(const T& other)` method.

What is "szone_free_definite_size" doing?

Comment: It looks like some memory allocation stuff (`malloc`, `free`...). I'd concentrate more upon implementation of `T::operator=(const T& other)` and/or why is it called so often that memory allocation takes up too much time.

Comment: From [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-594.1.4/gen/magazine_malloc.c) it looks like it small size allocation/deallocation library function.